# How to SELECT * and get all field alphabetical ordered

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This could be a strange question.

I have a table with 100+ columns. I would like to `SELECT *` all columns and get the resulting query with columns ordered alphabetically.

Is it possible in T-SQL?

Thanks

Comment: No. You have to do that manually

Comment: Not without resorting to dynamic sql.

Comment: Why do you care what order the columns are in?  That a _lot_ easier to do in the display layer (app, report, whatever)

Comment: One option is to create a view with the columns in order.    Some what manual but easy to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could build a dynamic SQL statement using the information available in the system catalog view.

The sample code below shows how:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @tbl NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'your_table' -- this is your source table

SELECT @cols= ISNULL(@cols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(c.name)
FROM sys.tables t 
join sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = @tbl
ORDER BY c.name

SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + @cols + ' FROM ' + @tbl
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: As noted in the now removed answer the join with the `sys.tables` view is unneeded as you can use `c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableName')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

DynamicSQL (SQL Server) example:

```
declare @TABLE varchar(200) set @TABLE='persons'
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL='select '
select @SQL= @SQL + column_name + ','
from information_schema.columns where table_name=@TABLE order by column_name
select @SQL = left(@SQL,len(@SQL)-1) + ' from ' + @TABLE -- trims the trailing comma

--select @SQL -- If you want to see the query

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(MAX)='T'--pass your table name
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)='SELECT '
SELECT @SQL=@SQL+',' +NAME FROM
(
SELECT TOP 100  QUOTENAME(NAME)  AS NAME
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id =
(
SELECT OBJECT_ID FROM sys.tables
WHERE NAME =@Table
)
ORDER BY NAME
) AS SS


SELECT @SQL=STUFF(@SQL,8,1,'')+' FROM '+@Table


EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```